# C# - Media Player won't play my file (Formatting Issue)

Tags: c#, path, uri

I have a method that returns the full path of a file and then getting a media player to play it, it doesn't work even if the string is hard coded the same as the method that returns a full path. I think it may have something to do with the URI but not quite sure.

```
private void PlayMusic()//method that creates media player
{
    var Player = Utilities.GetMediaPlayer();
    Player.Open(GetURI());
    Player.Play();
}

private void btnBattleMusic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//gets the path
{
    Full = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:Death.wav");
    //MusicPath = Full.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
    MusicPath = @"C:\Users\ser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DNDSoundboard\DNDSoundboard\bin\Debug\Sounds\BattleMusicWolfBlood.mp3";
    PlayMusic();
}

private System.Uri GetURI()//method that gets the URI
{
    return new System.Uri(MusicPath); //IF THIS IS CHANGED TO "Full" it doesn't work.. I run it but it has no errors pop up.
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Ok, ignoring the missing slash, can you manually open this file from file explorer? Would it be played?

Comment: What mediaplayer do you try to use?

Comment: public static System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer GetMediaPlayer()
            {
                return new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
            } 
This is my media player method,
I added the slash to the code, it only returned "C:\\Death.wav" This value as opposed to without slash; which returned: "C:\\Users\\ser\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\DNDSoundboard\\DNDSoundboard\\bin\\Debug\\Death.wav" this value which is the correct path.
And yes the file plays from the file explorer. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried?    "C:\Death.wav"

Comment: Hey Derek, yes i've tried that, to no avail unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Full = Path.GetFullPath("C:BattleMusicWolfBlood.mp3");

After much playing around, I moved the sound into the Debug folder and it worked with the code above, previously I had it in another folder inside Debug under "Sounds".